# Spring JPA/ Hibernate : How to map polymorphic relation on non primary columns

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
class B{
@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "ITEM_TYPE"))
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
                @MetaValue(targetEntity = A.class, value = "A")
        })
@Cascade( { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID")
private A a;
...
...
}
```

I'm trying to **Join table A and table B** `where B.item_type ='A'` is **constant** and `B.item_id= A.id`.

It is throwing me

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKi1uuph2wrvxtx66s7n7i1s09a:B [item_type,item_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (A [id])
```

Any help on How shall i map this using spring jpa and hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not to clear but below may help

Join table A and table B where B.item_type ='A' is constant and B.item_id= A.id.

1) B.item_type = 'A' : Create A enum and pass it while querying 
2) B.item_id=A.id :

lets says it is one to many relation.

```
Class B{

 @OneToMany
 @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DETACH)
 @JoinColumns(@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "item_id", insertable = false, updatable = false))
List<A> retunedList;

}
```

In case when it will be one to one, Change Annotaion to @onetoOne and make return type A instead of list.

Comment: Thanks I had similar approach using WhereClause, But This Works while fetching but doesn't work while insert and update.

Comment: If you define CascadeType.ALL instead of DETACH it will let you do all operations. check this for more detail information https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Comment: Agreed. This would work in case of Join from one table to the other as polymorphic. If we could use WhereClause or as you mentioned set the type prior as enum value.  Which suffices my current example. But as per your example, insertable=false wouldn't allow to run insert queries on table joins. Also I was looking for a bo-directional solution like **@OneToAny** and **@AnyToOne**. Unfortunately currently hibernate doesn't support **@AnyToOne.** Reference : [https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4320]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by a alternate approach where I made the associated entity as @Transient and then I saved that transient entity on @PostPersist call from parent entity by adding an EntityListener class.