# How to make query vie Spring Data and One To Many?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have some couple of entities:

**Task:**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String title;

    private boolean done;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

**User:**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Task> tasks;
}
```

The problem is making `spring data` query for `user` entity with task conditions. I'd like to do something like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<Stream<User>> getAllByTasksDoneTrue();
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I make the query to get users with completed tasks?

Comment: Does `Stream<User> getAllByTasksDoneIsTrue();` work?

Comment: This is what you are looking for I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840985/spring-jpa-hibernate-how-to-map-polymorphic-relation-on-non-primary-columns?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Barry I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Following quesry should work

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findAllByTask_Done(boolean status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (but there should be a better way !):

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("select u from User u where 0 = (select count(t) from u.tasks t where t.done = 'false')");
    List<User> getAllByTasksDoneTrue();
}
```

A minor comment is that this `t.done = 'false'` should be changed probably.

I know some databases do not support boolean type at all, so the condition depends on how actually this `done` property is stored in DB.

Comment: Yes, I see. But I'd like to do it without `sql` and database dependency.